# Sartre's "The transcendence of the ego"

Tags: kant, existentialism, phenomenology, sartre, husserl

In this text there are parts of Kant that Sartre refers to that I don't think I fully understand.

What parts of Kant would I have to refer to to understand where Sartre is coming from?

He refers to a Kantian "I think" and it is referred to separately from the I. What is this "I think" and how is it distinguished from the I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The 'I think'

> There is a version of the "Cogito" ['I think, therefore I exist': GT]
>    that Kant is found endorsing, but not in the manner intended by
>    Descartes. At B132 [of the Critique of Pure Reason] he says that,
>
> > It must be possible for the "I think" to accompany all my
> >      representations, otherwise, something would be represented in me
> >      which could not be thought at all, and that is equivalent to saying
> >      that the representation would be impossible, or at least would be
> >      nothing to me.
>
> Thus, the "I think" is a necessary condition, if an object is to be
>    thought at all. It is not a Cartesian device designed to defeat total
>    skepticism. Consciousness accompanies all thought, of course, and
>    "immediately includes in itself the existence of the subject; but it does
>   not so include any knowledge of that subject, and therefore also no
>    empirical knowledge, that is, no experience of it." (B277)

(Daniel N. Robinson, 'Kant's 'Seamless' Refutation of Idealism', The Review of Metaphysics, Vol. 64, No. 2 (DECEMBER 2010), pp. 291-301: 297-8.)

Roughly, Descartes used the fact of his thinking to 'prove' (by steps not necessary to explain here) that thinking was his essential nature; he was essentially a thinking being.

Kant's counter-position is to say that yes, when I am conscious and have various 'representations' - experiences, perceptions - then I am aware that I am the subject that has them. I am aware of them as mine. That, however, tells us nothing about the nature of the  'I'. I have no insight into the nature of the subject that has experiences even though I am that subject.

## Back to Kant

The best course, if you do not have time or inclination to read Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, is to read a summary or commentary. Roger Scruton's *Kant - A Very Short Introduction' (Oxford) would I think be of help.